# Two way custom binding with knockut 3 and es5 plugin

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0, knockout-es5-plugin

In my custom binding, I cannot write data back to model. The problem is that there is no way to write into "writable" property.

In knockout 2 there was possibility to use `allBindingsAccessor()._ko_property_writers` 
But in version 3 there are no such thing.

```
  ko.bindingHandlers.htmlValue = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
      var handler;
      handler = function() {
        var value, writable;
        writable = valueAccessor();
        console.log(allBindingsAccessor());
        value = element.innerHTML;
        // NOTE In previous versions this could be used:
        //writable(value);
        //writable = value <-- this also does not update model, as writable is simple string
        // Or this:
        //allBindingsAccessor()._ko_property_writers

        return allBindingsAccessor().htmlValue = value;
      };
      ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "keyup", handler);
      ko.utils.registerEventHandler(document, "click", handler);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
      var value;
      value = valueAccessor();
      if (element.innerHTML !== value) {
        element.innerHTML = value;
      }
    }
  };

var data = {
    name: 'blah'
};

ko.track(data);
ko.applyBindings({data: data});
```

My html:

```
<div contenteditable="true" data-bind="htmlValue: data.name"></div>
<input data-bind="value: data.name, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"></input>
<input data-bind="value: data.name, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"></input>
```

Js fiddle with this example: http://jsfiddle.net/t5rWd/2/

**Expected behaviour:** Inputs should update after changing div content (it's contenteditable)

**Current behaviour:** It works like one-way binding, div get's updated but cannot update inputs.

Comment: Seems like it is problem with ES plugin because following works: 
var obs = ko.getObservable(data, 'name');
obs(value);

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994320/how-to-access-the-observables-in-custom-bindings-when-using-knockout-es5

Comment: Well I checked this answer, but in ko 3 there is no `_ko_property_writers property`. And writing `ko.getObservable(data, 'name')` for each binding is not feasible.

Comment: You are right, this is plugin problem, here is pull request to address this: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout-es5/pull/15/

Answer (score 0):

Note that OP's comment will in fact probably serve as an answer. This is a bug with the `knockout-es5-plugin`.

Given that OP's account is now inactive I'm posting this community wiki answer to preserve that info. The full comment:

> You are right, this is plugin problem, here is pull request to address this: [github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout-es5/pull/15](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout-es5/pull/15/) –  user133408 Jun 26 '14 at 12:42